как сделать через цикл for нумерацию по типу 000001, 000002 ... 002713 и так далее
Всем здравствуйте, мне нужно перебрать числа с помощью цикла фор и вывести их, цифры должны быть шестизначными, как я написал в заголовке.
file = open('codes.txt', 'a')

for i in range(1000000):
  file.write(f'\n{000000 + i}')

Заранее спасибо

for i in range(1000000):
  file.write(f'\n{i:06}')

подробности использования флагов форматирования: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/
